# Using C++14 with AVR-GCC (Arduino Uno)

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded, avr-gcc, platformio

I'm trying try get my Arduino code to compile with `-std=c++14` instead of the default `-std=gnu++11`. To this end, I added to my `platformio.ini`:

```
build_flags = -std=c++14
build_unflags = -std=gnu++11
```

However, when I then try to compile, I get the following linker errors:

```
<artificial>:(.text+0x20a4): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)'
```

(multiple times)

I seems that the `delete` operator is missing. I found some threads about adding it manually, which appears to be used to be necessary in the past with Arduino. However, this shouldn't be the case anymore, and with the default `gnu++11` I do not have this issue. Why is this missing with `c++14` (and later standards and their GNU extensions) and not with the default `gnu++11`?

I only have this problem with avr-gcc (for Arduino Uno), with arm-none-eabi-g++ (for Teensy), this problem does not occur.

Comment: It suggests your code uses dynamic memory allocation.  Generally ill-advised on an AVR in any event.

Comment: I know. It's fine if you're using it in the right way (to avoid fragmentation). In any case, it works fine with `gnu++11`, just not with later C++ versions. That doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: Fragmentation is not the only issue to consider (and if you are deleting allocations, you are implicitly not avoiding fragmentation). I don't know about C++14 on Arduino, but the Arduino platform presents a simplified subset of C++ to the extent that they largely avoid referring to C++ rather than "Sketch" at all. To that end, C++14 support may simply not have been implemented. You are kind of on your own. If you want to use all of C++, consider abandoning the Arduino framework and it's constraints altogether, for something more "grown up".

Comment: As far as I'm aware, AVR-GCC fully supports all of C++ (the language, that is), but not the complete standard library (due to size constraints, basically). Tbh I don't see why I would have to abandon the Arduino framework, since if anything this seems like a constraint of AVR-GCC. I'm also using the Arduino framework on the Teensy LC (an ARM MCU), where I don't have this issue.

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation requires platform specific support in the library porting layer, so C++ compliance is not really the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching around it turns out that C++ from C++14 on defines two additional `delete` operators:

> void operator delete  ( void* ptr, std::size_t sz ) noexcept;
> (5)     (since C++14)
> void operator delete[]( void* ptr, std::size_t sz ) noexcept;
> (6)     (since C++14)

> 5-6) Called instead of (1-2) if a user-defined replacement is provided, except that it's unspecified whether (1-2) or (5-6) is called when deleting objects of incomplete type and arrays of non-class and trivially-destructible class types. A memory allocator can use the given size to be more efficient. The standard library implementations are identical to (1-2).

(from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)

Looking at [ArduinoCore-avr's source](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/new.cpp), these are actually present, and defined as follows:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201402L
void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept {
  operator delete(ptr);
}
void operator delete[](void * ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept {
  operator delete[](ptr);
}
#endif // __cplusplus >= 201402L
```

However, it seems like there hasn't been a new release of ArduinoCore-avr in a while, and the last release predates this (relatively recent) code.

After adding the above definition to my code myself, it compiles :)